# How do I improve the performance of this LINQ query?

Tags: .net, performance, linq

How do i increase the performance of below linq query?

While running it, it threw an error of `System.OutOfMemoryException`.
*Note: I have a lot of records in `XrmContext.sun_POSSet` entity*

```
var a = (from temple in XrmContext.sun_POSSet
         select new POS()
         {
             id = temple.Id,
             Country = temple.sun_sun_country_sun_POS == null ? "" : temple.sun_sun_country_sun_POS.sun_name,
             CountryId = temple.sun_sun_country_sun_POS == null ? "" : temple.sun_sun_country_sun_POS.Id.ToString(),
             stringint = temple.sun_sun_stringint_sun_placeofstu == null ? "" : temple.sun_sun_stringint_sun_placeofstu.sun_name,
             stringintId = temple.sun_sun_stringint_sun_placeofstu == null ? "" : temple.sun_sun_stringint_sun_placeofstu.Id.ToString(),
             FullName = temple.sun_contact_sun_POS.FullName,
             EMail = temple.sun_contact_sun_POS.EMailAddress1,
             MobilePhone = temple.sun_contact_sun_POS.MobilePhone
         }).ToList<POS>();
```

Comment: If you have "lots of records" in this table, do you really need to be pulling them all back at once? Perhaps add a where clause to only pull out the relevant records?

Comment: This is one of the reasons that `IQueryable` exists. Before you call `ToList()`, `IQueryable` stores the query and what to do with the results but doesn't actually process them. Use `Skip()` and `Take()` to pull out the records you actually need. If you need to process them all, do it in batches of (say) 500

Comment: You can also use `IEnumerable` you can then stream process each item one by one. It is important to understand that when you do this any "rewind" of the stream is highly non-performant. This is the usual reason why many suggest you add `.ToList()` to each Linq query.

Comment: Small note. If you are using Entity Framework you may need to use the [`.AsStreaming()`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/QueryableExtensions.cs) extention.

Answer (score 3):

Without further information about the number of records, I'd say you're getting an `OutOfMemoryException` because you are calling `ToList()` on a dataset that is too large to be held in memory.

`ToList()` forces evaluation of the underlying `IQueryable<T>`, which in this case results in all records being returned to the client and instantiated in memory. In your case, there simply isn't enough room - and you shouldn't assume that there will be. **Make your datasets small when you bring them back to the client**.

You should consider using [`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882968%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882788%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to implement paging, or using an appropriate `Where()` clause to filter the data.

Comment: i have 100502 records